# How do I check my flagging record on Area 51?

Tags: support, flags, area-51, flag-history, 404-not-found

As of late, I have been flagging proposals on Area 51, primarily to alert moderators to proposals that have failed to meet minimum activity requirements but have not yet been closed or removed as current policy dictates. I decided that, before I continued the practice, I would check my flagging record to make sure that the flags I was raising were *helpful*. I don't want to get myself banned or otherwise restricted for doing things that are deemed counterproductive!

How can I check my flagging record for Area 51? Most Stack Exchange sites have a link from my profile to my flagging history, but I don't see one on my Area 51 profile. I tried to manually build a URL based on the link to my Meta Stack Exchange flagging history combined with the Area 51 website name and my Area 51 userid (https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/161991), but accessing it yields a Page Not Found error.

*How do I view my Area 51 flagging record?*

Comment: With no mods and no CM responsible for Area 51, I'm pretty sure flagging is just waste of time. There's just nobody on the other end who can handle them anyway.

Comment: There is no concept of helpful vs declined for Area 51 flags. They can only be dismissed / marked as "someone looked at it and the flag is no longer relevant." Even if the page existed, it would tell you literally nothing other than that a flag existed. (I'm honestly not even sure we keep the flags. The button to clear a flag is literally labeled as a "delete" button.)

Comment: @Glorfindel perhaps reverse the dupes, as the comment by animuson here provides an answer of sorts.